# How to randomly pick a numeric alphabetic password from a regular file

Tags: java, algorithm, batch-file, passwords, bigdata

I have over one million numeric alphabetic password like: "A2AB3", and these passwords will be saved in several files.

for example:

file1.txt: 
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 .....

file2.txt:
F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 .....

... ...

... ...

I have to randomly take 100,000 passwords from those files each time, once a password was taken, this password will be deleted, until all passwords was taken out.

Actually, these passwords was generated in sequence, like: "1, 2, 3, 4, ...". Once these passwords was taken up, a new batch of password files will be generated. This is for avoiding duplication data appears in history (all past files, including some empty files which is taken passwords up). Each time I pick and remove a password is for the same reason: "unique password in history".

My solution is: take and remove the first password every fixed line in file, I'm not sure it is efficient or not.

Or if anyone has a better solution for this problem, even overthrown my current whole solution (sequential passwords -> files -> take/delete passwords -> other sequential passwords -> files ... ...);

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing this? I suspect there may be an easier solution that doesn't involve faffing around with all these files.

Comment: Did you try something ? What's your problem ?

Comment: thanks for replaying, it's a real project. This system will generate large amounts of  codes(passwords) in batch, and each code should be unique. Because these codes is generated in batch (not the same time), so it has to ensure that every code should be unique. e.g, Day 1: The batch of codes has code, 'AAA' , Day 3: when the system generate a new batch of codes, it should be avoiding the 'AAA' . Certainly, every code should be unique.  I'm sorry for my English, if you can't understand some details, please just ask me. Thanks so much.